# Tips and tricks for adjusting and choosing proper sizes for tiff() outputs in R; image versus text often gets misproportioned when saving

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tiff

I have been struggling with finding the balance between choosing size, units etc. for the specific `tiff() output` and the corresponding text on axes, ticks and labels. I often find that the proportions between image size and axes text/labels easily gets imbalanced or misproportioned when saving. I reckon that I have missed out on basic tips and tricks for saving images.

The intention of this thread is to collect tips and tricks on how to nicely balance graphics and text for a `tiff() output`. I have produced an example of what the problem is below.

Please, find data `w` and script samples below.

I have produced this plot with dobbel y-axes:

[image]

The image has been screenshotted directly from R. It looks nice, so I would like to save it as a `tiff() file` for my manuscript.

I therefore write:

```
tiff("plot.tiff", width = 320, height = 180, units = 'mm', res = 300)
... (script below) ...
dev.off()
```

Unfortunately, when I locate my `tiff() file` in my Working Directory, it looks "too big" and nothing like the "Plot window" in R Studio, as shown above. I certainly have to "Zoom In" several times to yield the same quality in the R Plot Window, however, the plot consequently becomes too big in dimensions.

Here is a screenshot: 
[image]

Ideally, this specific plot is a part of a composite figure, shown here:

[image]

As you can see, it simply does not look very nice.

So, obviously, I have tried changing `width`, `height`, `res` and `units` in `tiff()`

```
tiff("plot.tiff", width = xx, height = xx units = 'mm', res = 300)
... (script below) ...
dev.off()
```

However, this often compromises the axes text and labels. Like this:

[image]

So, my question is, are there any solutions, tips, tricks etc. on how to adjust size of `tiff()` and text so it remains proportioned?

Script

```
w$WHO <- as.factor(w$WHO)
yaks <- c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)

ggplot() + theme_bw() +

  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = w$WHO[w$response==1]), stat = "count", alpha=0.2, colour="#1C73C2", fill="#ECF0F9") + 

  scale_y_continuous(name = "Number of progressions", breaks=yaks, sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 1 , name = "Progression rate per 100 person-yrs", breaks=yaks, labels=c("0","40","80","120","160","200","240","280","320","360"))) +
  scale_x_discrete(name="", drop = FALSE, labels =c("WHO-I\nn=32","WHO-II\nn=23","WHO-III\nn=16", "Unknown\nn=5")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 18)) +

  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 1, y = 0.2677376), size=10, alpha=0.7, shape=18, colour="red") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 2, y = 3.2870709), size=10, shape=18,alpha=0.7, colour="red") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 3, y = 16.98), size=10, shape=18,alpha=0.7, colour="red") +

  annotate("text", x = c(1,2,3, 4) , y = c(-0.5, 2.2870709, 15.98, 0.5),  label = c("5.4","65.7","339.6", "0 events"), col="red", fontface=2, cex=4)+ 

  theme(axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red", size = 11), 
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=14,face="bold", margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "#1C73C2", size = 11), 
        axis.title.y.right=element_text(size=14,face="bold", margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 20)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 11))
```

Data

```
w <- structure(list(WHO = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L), response = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L), rfs = c(547.875, 60.875, 395.6875, 517.4375, 669.625, 
60.875, 182.625, 152.1875, 365.25, 243.5, 91.3125, 60.875, 30.4375, 
639.1875, 60.875, 1308.8125, 121.75, 60.875, 121.75, 152.1875, 
3.04375, 4169.9375, 121.75, 2648.0625, 517.4375, 730.5, 2191.5, 
578.3125, 426.125, 2526.3125, 2069.75, 1704.5, 1734.9375, 547.875, 
426.125, 474.825, 270.89375, 456.5625, 499.175, 234.36875, 2298.03125, 
91.3125, 1667.975, 675.7125, 365.25, 435.25625, 182.625, 365.25, 
663.5375, 182.625, 91.3125, 365.25, 91.3125, 182.625, 91.3125, 
91.3125, 365.25, 295.24375, 91.3125, 91.3125, 365.25, 91.3125, 
182.625, 91.3125, 182.625, 121.75, 1521.875, 639.1875, 913.125, 
152.1875, 334.8125, 365.25, 121.75, 547.875, 182.625, 91.3125
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 70L, 71L, 
72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 
85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 
98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 
109L, 111L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(c(`36` = 36L, 
`37` = 37L, `38` = 38L, `39` = 39L, `40` = 40L, `41` = 41L, `42` = 42L, 
`43` = 43L, `44` = 44L, `45` = 45L, `46` = 46L, `47` = 47L, `48` = 48L, 
`49` = 49L, `50` = 50L, `51` = 51L, `52` = 52L, `53` = 53L, `54` = 54L, 
`55` = 55L, `56` = 56L, `57` = 57L, `58` = 58L, `59` = 59L, `60` = 60L, 
`61` = 61L, `62` = 62L, `63` = 63L, `64` = 64L, `65` = 65L, `66` = 66L, 
`67` = 67L, `68` = 68L, `69` = 69L, `110` = 110L), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: Good question. The only way I know is trial and error.

Comment: Really good question! I also struggle with this and the trial and error method is all I've come up with. Makes it pretty complicated when people ask for changes though. Shame more people haven't given their thoughts on this.